# Is there a way to get all the downloads posted to the DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-download-manager

The issue I am facing is at some point some of my files downloaded via [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) are getting deleted. I see other files also getting deleted by the [DonwloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) at the same time. So my assumption is some other app is deleting the files but for that, the app needs to get the list of files downloaded via the download manager.

I have checked the API reference and the [DownloadManager.query()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Query.html) method only gives the download entries posted by the requesting app. Is there any other way to get all downloads posted to the download manager by some other app.

> All my download requests are marked as
>   `request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false)` and don't show up on
>   Downloads app.

At the time of deletion, the logs printed by the DownloadManager are

```
4819 14535 V DownloadManager: Deleting /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/..... via provider delete
```

Has anyone else faced this kind of issue?

> Device info: [ASUS ZenFone Max (ASUS_Z010D](http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_zenfone_max_zc550kl-7476.php))

Comment: I edited your title because it appeared to be asking for an API, and asking for off site resources is off topic. Just to be safe

Comment: By API I meant Android API. Didn't think it could convey offsite resources. Thanks for the correction.